# Is there a term for words that are spelled the same in a foreign language?

Tags: terminology

Is there a term for words that are spelled identically in a foreign language and have the same meaning (regardless of whether they sound the same)?

Comment: Who exactly would have need of such a word? Would it make any difference if they *sounded* the same too?

Comment: A software developer trying to solve one of the hardest problem in all of software development: *naming things*..

Comment: It does not matter if they sound the same

Comment: What about if one one the languages doesn't normally use the English alphabet? Does *Peking* count? What about *Beijing*?

Comment: Identical spelling down to a letter, so any language that doesn't use latin characters does not have such words with English. There are lots of such words between closely related languages such as Romanian and Italian and Catalan and French.

Comment: I've just realized that it's good enough for my case if the term only includes words of the same etymological origin that are spelled the same (removed that bit from the question).

Comment: Spanish and English share a lot of words in common: *bar, embargo, propaganda, chocolate, marijuana, cigar, patio, color, global, cafeteria, café, culpable, civil, honor, principal, corral, iguana, guerilla, armada, playa, plaza, poncho, mosquito, banana, puma, tilde, loco, fiesta, siesta, macho, tequila, taco, cilantro, piñata, jalapeño, piña colada*. :) Not to mention *Colorado, Florida, Nevada,* et cetera.

Comment: While learning swedish, I had a list of "false friends" - words that spelled and often sounded the same, but meant (slightly) different things. The words meaning the same thing usually are the "same word", often loanwords in at least one, sometimes both of the languages. Those sometimes sound different, because the speakers from the loaning language not necessarily know the language they loaned the word from (in swedish often the word develops a different spelling over time, but there are some still spelled like the original, but sounding different).

Comment: Meanwhile, *I* think it's a better fit for Linguistics.SE or, given his comment, Programmers

Comment: As I said in my (attempted) answer, I think a more detailed question. I also think that, while this may be of interest here, you might be better served elsewhere. You didn't tell us what you've already tried/considered ... did you see these?  //  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553082/do-you-code-variables-in-your-language/55316  //  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/do-people-in-non-english-speaking-countries-code-in-english/5504  //  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/169981/where-to-find-common-database-abbreviations-in-spanish/170053#170053

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest I believe is "cognate" (from [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cognate)
):
3
a: related by descent from the same ancestral language
b: of a word or morpheme : related by derivation, borrowing, or descent

However, translators must beware of cognates, because the meaning and usage often varies in subtle ways between languages. For instance, "mist" in German" is what farmers put on the field at night, causing a steam (ie a 'mist') to appear above the field the next morning that obscures sight.

Comment: Usually, *cognate* means *words of shared etymology*, but not necessarily spelled, pronounced, or used in the same way. As Wikipedia says, a typical example is [English *starve* and Dutch *sterven* or German *sterben* ("to die")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate). In OP's case I'd be inclined to just say they are ***the same word***.

Comment: As I noted, there is apparently no term *closer* to his intended meaning than 'cognate'.

Comment: Note however [the phrase "exact cognate"](http://www.sheltonpublicschools.org/subsite/sis/teacher/672/cognates-15662) which seems to narrow the meaning much closer to what the Question asks.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is true that it refers to words of "shared etymology," but note that words of unshared etymology that sound similar or are spelled the same with different meanings are often called "false cognates." (Point being that cognate is still used)

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_French_words_and_phrases_used_by_English_speakers

In the above wikipedia article are a list of French words which have retained their original meaning and spelling. As far as I could tell, a single word or expression meaning *unmodified foreign words* (my definition) which have been adopted into the English language, does not exist.

(Emphasis mine)

> This article, however, covers words and phrases that generally entered the lexicon later, [...] As such, they have not lost their character
>   as Gallicisms, or words that seem unmistakably foreign and "French" to
>   an English speaker. The phrases are given as used in English, and may
>   seem correct modern French to English speakers, but may not be
>   recognized as such by French speakers as many of them are now defunct
>   or have drifted in meaning. **A general rule is that, if the word or
>   phrase retains French diacritics or is usually printed in italics, it
>   has retained its French identity.**

A similar list exists for [Italian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aItalian_words_and_phrases) words and phrases, again these words retain their "ethnical" spelling and meaning however, their pronunciation may differ from that of Italian.

On a side note, [**Loanwords**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword) or its equivalent expression *lexical borrowing*, expresses the concept of foreign words which were adopted and manipulated in the past and today appear and sound native-like. For example the English adjective, handy, was *loaned* to the German language but means mobile phone consequently "Handy" is a German noun.

**EDIT:**

In The Cambridge Encyclopedia of Language, (*Edition 2010*) *David Crystal*. The author states on p302

> When languages have been shown to have a common ancestor, they are
>   said to be *cognate*.
>
> The clearest cases are those where the parent language is known to
>   exist. For example, on the basis of the various words for 'father' in
>   the Romance languages, it is possible to see how they all derived from
>   the Latin word *pater*.

Examples:

> *Italian* padre; *Spanish* padre; *French* père; *Portuguese* pai; *Catalan* pare.

on p340, Crystal talks about language changes; sound, grammatical, and semantic. Under the heading of *New words and old* he makes the following remarks:

> In most languages the vast majority of new words are in fact
>   borrowings from other languages [...] Borrowing proceeds in all
>   directions, *Weekend* and *parking* have been borrowed by French from
>   English; *chic* and *savoir-faire* have been borrowed by English from
>   French. Some languages have borrowed so extensively that native words
>   are in a minority

In nowhere (could I find) does the esteemed author, David Crystal, mention a linguistic word, phrase or term which means native and foreign words having the same meaning and spelling.

Comment: I believe the only realistic term the OP could use is "borrowed foreign words" but that does not guarantee its spelling is identical to its "parent" language.

Comment: Careful, "handy" is a (slang) noun in English, too.   "Give me a handy" or "How much for a handy?" would get a very different reaction in some places ...   (Although, to go way too far with this - I bet they cover a similar price range.)

Comment: *"Some languages have borrowed so extensively that native words are in a minority"*   Interesting, although it sounds like a stretch.  Does he say which?

Comment: Not in that specific page/section/chapter, he doesn't. It's quite a hefty volume so there might be references elsewhere.

Comment: @hunter2 I've never heard of that expression handy being used that way before. (But I have a good idea what it means!)

Comment: Admittedly, I don't hear it that often; once in a while, and at least once on a fairly popular TV show. Then again, how often *would* it come up? Ahem. // If you come across a more detailed reference at some point, please post it.   I love how many there seem to be in Japanese (and how easy to spot), but it's a very far cry from making a large share of the total vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

"**Homograph**" (almost, sorta) means what you want - two words that are spelled the same.   As a comment points out, you should be careful of words that look the same but have different meanings - what another comment calls "false friends".   "Homograph" does not specifically denote words from different languages, although that may be a finer distinction than you're inclined to make.

Related (but not what you are seeking): "**Homonym**" is a more commonly used word which, I think, also indicates that the words are pronounced the same.   To round it out, "**Homophone**" would be 'sound-alike'.

More detail in the question would be nice, but I think (from a comment) might also end with "this is a discussion for Programmers.SE or its chat room".

Comment: **homographs** plural
Each of two or more words spelled the same but not necessarily pronounced the same and having different meanings and origins (e.g., bow1 and bow2)

Comment: OP specifically asks for: words that are spelled *identically* in a *foreign* language and have the **same meaning**. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_homographs

Comment: However, on reflection the words are useful to know and the OP might find them "handy" in the future.

Comment: Changed my downvote

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks.  I appreciate that you left a comment with it, and I think that my changes based on your comments improved the answer.   The system works! (sometimes ...)